# Effect of type casting on printf function

Tags: c, formatting, printf, behavior

Here is a question from my book,

[image]

Actually, I don't know what will be the effect on printf function, so I tried the statements in the original system of C lang. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int x = 4;
  printf("%hi\n", x);
  printf("%hu\n", x);
  printf("%i\n", x);
  printf("%u\n", x);
  printf("%li\n", x);
  printf("%lu\n", x);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw46Lqyw/M0UhNzEzT0NToZpLQSEzr0ShQsFWwcQayCkoAnLTNJRUMzJj8pR0FCo0UUVLsYliVYpVZQ5WpTkItbX//wMA)

So, the output is very simple. But, is this really the solution to above problem?

Comment: The format specifier tells `printf` what the type of the next argument is. The parameters are passed as integers in this case. `printf` will take the parameter and interpret it as the type told by the format specifier.

Comment: The table of data types is a bit funny. There can be only one integer size `unsigned` or `signed`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - Do you mean that only `int`s can satisfy the details in table, and hence the given code's output is the only possible solution?

Comment: `unsigned X` is an int of at least 8 bits (since `unsigned Z` is an int of 8 bits). `printf` uses `%xu` to extract two bits from `num` to print it as unsigned.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie If I understand correctly X Y and Z are not variable names but a part of the type name.

Comment: This is some seriously confusing assignment `%x` and `%z` are valid format specifiers... `%y` is not. Is the task to replace those format specifiers with something else, or what?

Comment: In either case, the assignment can't be answered without knowing the size of `int` on the specific system.

Comment: @Lundin - of course, but in this question, we're supposed to assume a new system, where `%x` or `%z` don't exist. And, neither int, float or double!

Comment: But the result depends on whether there's implicit integer promotion or not in the call of the variadic function `printf`. You might also want to nudge the author of the book and tell them that C is case-sensitive and there's nothing called `Printf`... what crap book is this, please share so we can shame it on the Internet.

Comment: @Lundin the size is known: the declaration `Y num` is declaring a 4 bytes integer. The really question is: would it be promoted to 8 bytes integer in case of 8 bytes format specifiers? Otherwise it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Lundin the assignment is assuming a custom implementation called `Printf`

Comment: @RobertoCaboni - Can you pls explain how is `Y num` declaring a 4 bytes integer?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes it is obviously an _integer_ but it is not obviously _int_, which is the relevant type in determining integer promotion. And some trashy custom function `Printf` is still variadic and thereby subject to default argument promotion.

Comment: @Lundin - I think the author misprinted `printf` as `Printf`, sorry from my side

Comment: Again, the question cannot be answered without knowing the size of `int`.

Comment: Text in the book is flawed: Sizes are defined in bits, but C doesn't allow integers smaller than 8. If we assume that it's a typo and byte was meant, then all types are capable of storing 42. But if we assume that this is hypothetical system and sizes are in bits, then in `Y num = 42;` value won't fit the type and it will result in implementation defined value or signal. In that case we cannot answer the question without knowing more about the implementation.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni *the size is known: the declaration Y num is declaring a 4 bytes integer.*  No, the image says 4 ***bits***, not bytes.  Toss this book into the garbage.  Never learn C from someone unable to keep bits and bytes straight.  And the question [can't be answered in general anyway](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9): "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, **the behavior is undefined**."

Comment: @AndrewHenle I actually misread "bytes"... Automatic word conversion acted by my brain...

Comment: @user694733: Where do you see text in the C standard that prohibits integers narrower than 8 bits? All objects must be represented with at least one byte, which must be at least 8 bits, but integers can have padding bits, so the value is represented using fewer bits than are in its representation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Actually, the arguments are all the correct **type** for the conversion specifications, since the argument in this case, `num`, will be promoted to `int`, and therefore the conversion specifications must be expecting an `int`. The actual problem is that the conversion specifications, by analogy with how `%hd` or `%hhd` work, is that the **value** must be one representable in the type identified by the conversion specification. E.g., if we `printf("%hhd", 'x');`, you will not complain that `'x'` is an `int` type (even before promotion) but is being printed with `%hhd`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But, as pointed out earlier by Lundin, there's no indication of the size of `int` in this implementation, so we don't know which argument types get promoted and which ones don't.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The range of `int` is at least −32767 to +32767, so all of these types get promoted.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You're assuming that "bits" isn't mean to be "bytes".  Given the value `42`, I suspect that's a typographical error.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: If it were bytes, the value of `42` would be completely unremarkable, producing the same output in each statement (aside from the promotion issue), and the exercise would have no point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I assumed that *Size* in the table meant full type size, not the type size excluding the padding bits. If it is the latter instead, then I guess such extended integer types are possible. I think this is another issue with question being poorly defined.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems in this question that make it unsuitable for teaching C.

First, to work on this problem at all, we have to assume a non-standard C implementation is used. In standard C, `%x` is a complete conversion specification, so `%xu` and `%xd` cannot be; the conversion specification has already ended before the `u` or `d`. And the uses of `z` in a conversion specification interferes with its standard use for `size_t`.

Nonetheless, let’s assume this C variant does not have those standard conversion specifications and instead uses the ones shown in the table but that this C variant otherwise conforms to the C standard with minimal changes.

Our next problem is that, in `Y num = 42;`, we have a plain `Y`, not the `signed Y` or `unsigned Y` shown in the table. Let’s assume `signed Y` is intended.

Then `num` is a signed four-bit integer. The greatest value it can represent is 0111<sub>2</sub> = 7<sub>10</sub>. So it cannot represent 42. Attempting to initialize it with 42 results in a conversion specified by C 2018 6.3.1.3, which says, in part:

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

The result is we do not know what value is in `num` or even whether the program continues to execute; it may trap and terminate.

Well, let’s assume this implementation just takes the low bits of the value. 42 is 1010102, so its low four bits are 1010. So if the bits in `num` are 1010, it is negative. The C standard permits several methods of representation for negative numbers, but we will assume the overwhelmingly most common one, two’s complement, so the bits 1010 in `num` represent −6.

Now, we get to the `printf` statements. Except the problem text shows `Printf`, which is not defined by the C standard. (Are you sure this problem relates to C code at all?) Let’s assume it means `printf`.

In `printf("%xu",num);`, if the conversion specification is supposed to work like the ones in standard C, then the corresponding argument **should** be an `unsigned X` value that has been promoted to `int` for the function call. As a two-bit unsigned integer, an `unsigned X` can represent 0, 1, 2, or 3. Passing it −6 is not defined. So we do not know what the program will print. It might take just the low two bits, 10, and print “2”. Or it might use all the bits and print “-6”. Both of those would be consistent with the requirement that the `printf` behave as specified for values that **are** in the range representable by `unsigned X`.

In `printf("%xd",num);` and `printf("%yu",num);`, the same problem exists.

In `printf("%yd",num);`, we are correctly passing a `signed Y` value for a `signed Y` conversion specification, so “-6” is printed.

Then `printf("%zu",num);` has the same problem with the value mismatched for the type.

Finally, in `printf("%zd",num);`, the value is again in the correct range, and “-6” is printed.

From all the assumptions we had to make and all the points where the behavior is undefined, you can see this is a terrible exercise. You should question the quality of the book it is in and of any school using it.